# Sorting a tuple by its float element

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, tuples

I am trying to sort this tuple by the value of the number, so that it be rearranged in descending order:

```
l =[('orange', '3.2'), ('apple', '30.2'), ('pear', '4.5')]
```

as in:

```
l2 =[('apple', '30.2'), ('pear', '4.5'), ('orange', '3.2')]
```

I am trying to sort it using this:

```
l2 = ((k,sorted(l2), key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)))
       [value for pair in l2 for value in pair]
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

How can I correct this so that I can indicate that I want to sort by the numbers in each pair? Python syntax still confuses me a lot, because I am very new to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are muddling up the syntax; you were almost there. This works:

```
l2 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

e.g. call the `sorted()` function, and pass in the list to sort as the first argument. The other two arguments are keyword arguments (`key`, and `reverse`).

Demo:

```
>>> l = [('orange', '3.2'), ('apple', '30.2'), ('pear', '4.5')]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
[('apple', '30.2'), ('pear', '4.5'), ('orange', '3.2')]
```

You can also sort the list in-place:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

with the same two keyword arguments.